jsPDF generated file wont show text inside the table
Im generating PDF file using jsPDF. Everything works fine if I view the file in the browser:

However once I open it using PDF-XChange Editor I get empty file:

Same with phones. On some phones it works on some it doesnt.
What might be the problem?
